# What is the purpose of these REG_BINARY keys for Office add-ins?

Tags: microsoft-office, windows-registry, microsoft-office-2013

While in the process of troubleshooting an Office add-in issue the other day, I noticed via procmon that Microsoft stores some binary registry keys for each add-in.

For example, under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Outlook\Addins\OneNote.OutlookAddin` I see:

[image]

Similar `REG_BINARY` keys exist for other add-ins too... not just the Microsoft-created add-ins. Yet, I can't seem to find any information on what these specific keys are for.  Is this published somewhere?  Or a Microsoft mystery?